# gradle org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedComponentResult not present

Tags: gradle, build

I'm trying to do a gradle build with SpringBoot and am getting this error:

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.3.0.RELEASE'
    jarName =  'SpringSampleMicroservice'
    jarVersion = ' -jar build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE")
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}
```

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")` 
only supports Gradle 2.2+

Simply upgrade and issue resolved!